# How to install Glade in Mac OSX El capitan

Tags: glade

I am trying to install Glade on mac OSX el capitan. I downloaded sources on https://glade.gnome.org/sources.html

I followed instructions with the text "Install" in the sources. Then when I am trying to configure "build", I received following messages:

```
Configuration:

Source code location:   .
Compiler:   gcc
GTK+ UNIX Print Widgets: yes
PYTHON Widgets support: no
Introspection Data:      yes
Build Reference Manual:  no
Build User Manual:
```

I am trying to find out on google how to download the program PYTHON Widgets support but without success.

So I am wondering if you know anything which can help me?

Best
Mia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to figure out the problem on my own.
So it is very simple, use macports to install glade.

Step 1 : install X11 on your mac or update it

Step 2 : install Xcode

Step 3: install macports 
 - macOS Sierra : https://github.com/macports/macports-base/releases/download/v2.3.5/MacPorts-2.3.5-10.12-Sierra.pkg

- OS X El Captain : https://github.com/macports/macports-base/releases/download/v2.3.5/MacPorts-2.3.5-10.11-ElCapitan.pkg

  - for other versions of os x, you can use this link: https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.source

Step 4:
In terminal do:

```
sudo port install glade@3.20.0
```

or just

```
sudo port install glade
```

Answer (score 6):

Easiest solution could be to install it via homebrew (https://brew.sh/):

```
$ brew install glade
```

Comment: The dependencies installed this way are all gtk+2 family. Is there a way to point to gtk+3?